# Nuxt + TypeScript types not working in layouts and plugins

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm new in TS and I want to use types in layouts too but as in the picture typescript-build returns error "`Syntax Error: Unexpected token`" when I add type to `popups` property.

In `pages` it works correctly. It's not working in `layout` and in `plugins` ts files.

Simplified not working VUE file is below.

```
<template>
  <div id="wrapper" class="d-flex no-gutters">
    <Nuxt/>
  </div>
</template>
<script type="ts">
import {Component, Vue} from 'nuxt-property-decorator'

@Component()
export default class Default extends Vue {
  popups: {
    [key: string]: {
      show: boolean,
      loading: boolean,
      changed: boolean,
      submit_loading: boolean
    }
  } = {
    login: {
      show: false,
      loading: false,
      changed: false,
      submit_loading: false
    }
  };
}
</script>
```

[image: Syntax Error: Unexpected token]

Comment: please share the code as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script should have the value `ts` for the `lang` attribute :

```
 <script lang="ts">
```

Comment: But @BoussadjraBrahim , it's working in VUE files in `pages`. I think there must be another right way. it must work in layouts too or I'm wrong?

Comment: Ah ok, the problem is in the script type attribute which should be `<script lang="ts">` instead of `<script type="ts">`